# Stipple shading in Plot3D - color and grain control

Tags: plotting

Following line of code

```
SphericalPlot3D[
 Sin[\[Theta]^2] + 2 Cos[2 \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 
  2 Pi}, Axes -> False, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 PlotStyle -> StippleShading[0.45, White], Lighting -> "Accent", 
 Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None]
```

produce

[image]

1. how to make it inverse, black dots on white surface?
2. is it possible to control grain of the stippling similar to this solution:
   [grain control](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219020/control-grain-size-of-stipple-shading) in case of Plot3D?

Comment: Something like `SphericalPlot3D[Sin[θ^2] + 2 Cos[2 θ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> False, PlotTheme -> "Classic", PlotStyle -> StippleShading[0.45, Black], Lighting -> "Accent", Boxed -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None]`?

Comment: Yes, this is great for the a) part